# How to include an html file in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a simple use case where I want to pick html from a seperate file and append it somewhere else after some operations in javascript.

**forms.html**

```
<div id="forms">
   <p>This is sample content of forms</p>
</div>
```

I want to include this file in my scripts & get its inner contents and append it to some other div.

**scripts.js:**

```
function drawFormContent(params){

    var str = '';
    str += '<div id="forms">';
    str += '<p>This is sample content of forms</p>';
    str += '</div>';
    // this str variable should be picked from forms.html file
    document.getElementById("mainContent").innerHTML = str;
}
```

Where my main page looks like this:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div id="mainContent"></div>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        drawFormContent();
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the tagged duplicate answer your question?  If it doesn't please explain why not and explain with as much detail as possible why not.

Comment: @zero298 isnt .load() a jquery function? I need this to be acheived by pure javascript

Comment: The second answer to that question is pure JS with no jq and provides an example using `fetch` and `XHMHttpRequest`.

Comment: @zero298 I am getting this issue: Reason: CORS request not http. Even though the file is in same directory

Comment: That's a bit of a different question, but if you show exactly how you tried to load the HTML in your question including what URL scheme you used (`http://` vs `file://`) we might be able to help.  There are generally more issues whenever you work on a site over `file://`.  See ["Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." error when loading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10752055/691711) and consider using some local HTTP server if you aren't already.